# Unicodedata.normalize() ValueError: invalid normalization form

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I'm trying to take foreign language text and output a human-readable, filename-safe equivalent. After looking around, it seems like the best option is `unicodedata.normalize()`, but I can't get it to work. I've tried putting the exact code from some answers here and elsewhere, but it keeps giving me this error. I only got one success, when I ran:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFD', '\u00C7')
'C\u0327'
```

But every other time, I get an error. Here's my code I've tried:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', u'\u2460') #error, not sure why. Look same as above.
s = 'ذهب الرجل'
unicodedata.normalize('NKFC',s) #error
unicodedata.normalize('NKFD', 'ñ') #error
```

Specifically, the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid normalization form
```

I don't understand why this isn't working. All of these are strings, which means they are unicode in Python 3. I tried encoding them using `.encode()`, but then `normalize()` said it only takes arguments of string, so I know that can't be it. I'm seriously at a loss because even code I'm copying from here seems to error out. What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at [unicodedata.c](http://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/unicodedata.c#L817), the only way you can get that error is if you enter an invalid *form* string. The valid values are "NFC", "NFKC", "NFD", and "NFKD", but you seem to be using values with the "F" and "K" switched around:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>>
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NKFD', 'ñ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid normalization form
>>>
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', 'ñ')
'ñ'
```